# Какое слово ранее обозначало число 11 в русском языке?

Tags: лингвистика

Во многих языках для чисел 11 и 12 сохранились уникальные числительные, а составные числительные начинаются с 13. Насколько я понимаю это наследство двенадцатиричной системы счисления. 
В русском языке я знаю слово для числа 12: дюжина. А есть ли такое числительное для числа 11?
Если есть, то когда одинадцать и двенадцать вытеснили прежние варианты?
Если нет, то откуда в русском языке появилось слово дюжина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В русском одиннадцать и двенадцать - исходные обозначения для числительных 11 и 12. "Дюжина" никогда не было основным названием для 12, это очень позднее (XVII или даже XVIII век) заимствование из французского или итальянского.

Кстати, в отношении "других" языков, тоже надо разбираться, являются ли "самостоятельные" слова для обозначения 11 и 12 (иногда - и далее до 19) исконными или тоже образованы в поздние периоды.